server returned an error response: error code -32000: insufficient funds for gas *

I have more than 0.133 ETH, but sometimes it shows "Future Pending Clear Transaction" and other times it shows an "Out of Funds" error.
Github:- https://github.com/sanu2002/checkup
Please look at  my code and let me know where i am doing wrong .


It's working fine on my end, as you can see from this transaction hash.

Just ensure that the account named vrf, which you're using from the keystore, has sufficient LINK tokens to cover the FUND_AMOUNT (i.e., 3 in your case) that you're transferring in the transferAndCall of your Interaction.s.sol file.
Also, make sure to add the block.chainid condition in the constructor of your NetworkConfig.s.sol, like:
constructor() {
    if (block.chainid == 11155111) {
        networkConfig[ETH_SEPOLIA_CHAIN_ID] = getSepoliaEthConfig();
    } else {
        localNetworkConfig = getOrCreateAnvilConfig();
    }
}

Otherwise, it will deploy the mock contracts unnecessarily on the Ethereum Sepolia network as well.

But Patrick approached it differently, and I’m trying to set up the entire workflow my way. Due to the constructor, I ended up spending more on gas fees.

If you don't add the block.chainid condition in the constructor, then the gas fees would be higher and that too for the unneccessary deployments that are only needed for local chain, not for the Sepolia chain, because it would call the getOrCreateAnvilConfig function irrespective of the current network.

Let me know if you are still facing the same error by having your wallet (corresponding to the keystore account) funded with at least 3 LINK tokens.


Now it's working fine after forge script script/Interaction.s.sol:Fundsubscriotion  --rpc-url $ETH_SEPOLIA_URL   --private-key $Private_key   --broadcast   --gas-price 250000

Thanks for helping me !!!
Another question : How do i know how much gas price  i need to overcome the previous future transaction error ??In my case i added 250000 (should i check in explorer ?),So finally wen i will face the error like this i need to increase the [[ gas price  + gas used  ]] to overcome the errorcode:32000 future transaction tries to replace the pending !!

as Syed mention the reason for failure may not have been due to gasprice config but because of insufficient VRF subscription balance. Also network spikes can cause fluctuations that make an adequate subscription balance inadequate at the time of the spike. Sometimes retrying after a few minutes can help.  It is not clear that the reason it worked for you the second time is because you passed --gasprice in the forge command.

This issue is not related to the VRF subscription balance. Once you look at my code, you will understand how the code flow works. The issue was caused by a future transaction attempting to replace a pending transaction. In Ethereum, transactions are ordered in the mempool according to their nonce number, from lower to higher. Until a lower nonce transaction is executed (which might be delayed due to congestion), higher nonce transactions cannot be executed. To overcome this situation, the lower nonce transaction needs to be executed with a higher gas fee.
